# What's an optimum build for a set-up character for Pathfinder Society character?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, pathfinder-society

My wife plays a barbarian in [Pathfinder Society](http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety) that does massive amounts of damage when she is able to use Cleave. I decided to build a character that would reposition foes for her to cleave.

What's the best build to accomplish this? It doesn't have to be a Cavalier, but keep in mind that leveling will not be very fast. Builds that require 3rd or 4th level to work at all aren't viable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first attempt was a Cavalier from the APG that uses Improved Bull Rush and the teamwork feat that gives +2 on CMB. With that, his Bull Rush CMB is on order of 9 or 10 at first level. In later levels, he could pick up the feats for shield bashing that give free bull rushes.

Answer (score 6):

Fighter with Improved Reposition, Weapons Focus - Longspear*
Stand 10' away, use reposition to move the person where you want them (back to your wife) and let her wail away.

IIRC, should be Str+1(weapon focus)+2(Improved Reposition)+1(bab). Assuming a str of 18 (16+2racial) thats +8 at 1st level w/o teamwork feat (so you don't need to be human). Throw in a masterwork weapon and that should be +9. This allows you to literally move you foe 5' in the direction you want. Drag and Bull rush builds could also be used I guess, but reposition allows you to turn them. This makes it MUCH easier to flank (and use that teamwork super-flanking feat)

* It really could be any weapon, I like the reach aspect though